# Get network data with nodejs

Tags: node.js, network-programming

I am looking for a way to get complete data from the network of my own website with nodejs, exactly like in the network tab of the chrome devtool.

But, surprinsingly, I cannot find any information about it.

What I need is actually to get data from requests made by an iframe located on my webpage. But the tricky thing is that these specific requests don`t pass by my server. Is there a way to access these requests as I would in the network tab of chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I found is to create a chrome plugin, it takes some effort but then I could catch any request.